# Using list.js and multiple search boxes to sort on limited fields per box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using list.js as a way of quickly sorting through a list of elements. I have it set up right now with the search box being able to sort along any of the parameters, but I want to set it up so that, for instance, the first box will sort by the name, and then a second box that will sort by either type or type2.

This will allow a user to, in my example case here, use the first box to search by a name, and then the second box to further refine results. I'm afraid of what I think the solution may be, which is to include another copy of the data with fewer fields and hidden that the boxes search on, but even in that less-than-optimal case I'm not sure of the approach to take to translate the results found in that search with the name search.

This is what I have so far, and it all works like a charm, but any help pushing this toward what I need would be helpful.

```
<div id="results">
    <input class="search" /><br />
    <span class="sort" data-sort="name">Sort by Pokemon Name</span><br />
    <span class="sort" data-sort="type">Sort by Pokemon Type</span><br />
    <span class="sort" data-sort="type2">Sort by Second Type</span><br />
    <span class="sort" data-sort="number">Sort by Number</span><br />
    <ul class="list"></ul>
</div>
    <script>
        var options = {
        item: '<li><h3 class="name"></h3><p class="type"></p><p class="type2"></p></li>'
         };

        var values = [
            {name: 'Bulbasaur', type: 'Grass', type2: 'Poison', number: '001'}
        , {name: 'Ivysaur', type: 'Grass', type2: 'Poison', number: '002'}
        , {name: 'Venusaur', type: 'Grass', type2: 'Poison', number: '003'}
    ];
var pokeList = new List('results', options, values);
</script>
```

Comment: Found any solution to this?